# Data Structures and Color Data Types in FastLED

Tags: data-type

So i'm doing something wrong but i don't exactly know what and hope somebody can give me a quick pointer:

I declared a starting color for my fastled animation:

```
CHSV startcolor(100, 255, 255);
```

and then a data structure

```
typedef struct {

int currentBrightness = 0;

int targetBrightness = 0;

int updown;

CHSV color = startcolor;

} blinkblink, *pblinkblink;
```

So basically my idea is to have every LED be represented with this data structure to control brightness within an anmation. However if i now set

```
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
```

and do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(myLeds); i++) {

leds[i] = myLeds[i].color;

}

FastLED.show();
```

nothing happens. I'm pretty sure, that this is because i'm somehow not understanding the data type thing. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you did not use the name of the struct `blinkblink` .... http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

Comment: Where have you defined the `myLeds` array?

Comment: Your **second mistake** was not observing the complete and reproducible parts of [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Once you fix that error, others will have a chance to help you with your **first error** (i.e. why doesn't my code work?)